# How can all the options be correct in this question?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

**Question**: The equations of two sides $AB$ and $AC$ of an isosceles triangle $ABC$ are $x+y=5$ and $7x-y=3$ respectively. If the area of the Triangle $ABC$ is 5 sq. units , then the possible equations of the side $BC$ is (are): ?

$A). x-3y+1=0$
$B). 3x+y+2=0$
$C). x-3y-21=0$
$D). 3x+y-12=0$

Answer given :$A,B,C,D$

**Making an attempt:** Obviously, $A$ must be $(1,4)$. Now after that, if I consider a point $(x_1,y_1)$ on $AB$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ on $BC$,  I could see that the area should be :

$$\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}1&4&1\\x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1 \end{bmatrix}=5$$
(treat  it as a determinant please)

And, I assumed that $AB=BC$ which gave me:

$$(2-x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_1)=(8-y_1-y_2)(y_1-y_2)$$

But sadly none of the equations could satisfy these conditions. True enough, my assumption can be wrong but I can't seem to make any headway in this question. Please Guide

Comment: it's not that all options are simultaneously true, it's that they are all possible

Comment: Option B as written doesn’t have the right area. On the other hand, $3x+y-2=0$ does. Are you sure you copied it down correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, $B(a,5-a);C(b,7b-3)$

We have $$(a-1)^2+(5-a-4)^2=(b-1)^2+(7b-3-4)^2$$

$$\iff2(a-1)^2=50(b-1)^2\implies a-1=\pm5(b-1)$$

For $a-1=5(b-1), a=5b-4$

$\implies|BC|^2=(a-b)^2+(5-a-7b+3)^2=(5b-4-b)^2+\{8-7b-(5b-4)\}^2=(b-1)^2(4^2+12^2)$

Now if $M$ is the midpoint of $BC,M:\left(\dfrac{a+b}2,\dfrac{5-a+7b-3}2\right)$

Replace $a$ with $5b-4$

Now $|AM|$ is also the perpendicular distance of $BC$ from $A$

We have $$\dfrac{|AM|\cdot|BC|}2=5$$

Similarly for $a-1=-5(b-1)$

Comment: See also: http://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/prove-that-in-an-isosceles-triangle-altitude-is-also-the-med/math/8216757

Answer (score 0):

Using [Theorem](http://ceemrr.com/Geometry1/RightTriangles/RightTriangles4.html): In an isosceles triangle the bisector of the vertex angle cuts the opposite side in half.

Now the equation of $AM$ where $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$

$$\dfrac{x+y-5}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=\pm\dfrac{7x-y-3}{\sqrt{7^2+1^2}}$$

$$\iff5(x+y-5)=\pm(7x-y-3)$$

From the other answer, $M(3b-2,6-b)$

So, we can find $b$

Also, use $AM\perp BC$

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote! I'm eager to learn the mistake here.

Comment: I cannot be sure but my guess is that the downvote came from posting two solutions that overlap significantly. FWIW I upvoted your other answer because it gives a simple way to do the algebra. This answer doesn't IMHO add anything.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,  I'm least interested in the up-vote.I think down-vote is a nice mechanism to pinpoint the mistakes. For better clarity I wrote the second answer. I believe the two post diverge sufficiently.